# Java regex allow only specific characters

Tags: java, regex

The method should allow only letters, whitespace, commas, dots, colons, semi-colons, question marks, exclamation marks, hyphens, single quotes and double quotes in a palindrome. If there are any other characters, then the text cannot be a palindrome

```
if(userInput.matches("\\d.*[^a-zåäöA-ZÅÄÖ .,;:?!-'\"]+")) {
        return false;
```

So i've been trying to make it so the input allows only letters and these specific special characters, but I don't seem to get it work. For example now it allows # and $, although i haven't listed them in the regex.

Comment: Why would punctuation be included in a palindrome? Punctuation is not palindromic as a rule

Comment: I think it's just so we have to practice removing the special characters from the string.

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}]+", "");` first is what I'd do

Comment: userInput = userInput.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""); is how i removed the special characters but that isn't the problem. The problem is that the method should return false if any of the not allowed characters is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match is: 1 digit, any characters, one or more of not ... .

Mind `!-'` is a range meaning `!"#$%&'`. Place the minus at the end `... -]` instead.

*(BTW I did not understand the code's intention.)*

---

It seems you want to find a non-legal character to return false.
You do that by listing the legal characters in a negative group `[^...]`.

```
if (userInput.matches("(?s).*[^a-zåäöA-ZÅÄÖ .,;:?!'\"-].*")) {
    return false;
}
```

The command `(?s)` will let `.` also match line breaks like `\n`.

In one non-legal character is found one can fail.

Comment: *The problem is that the method should return false if any of the not allowed characters is entered.* The same problem. Return m.matches pattern [a-zA-Z]+

Comment: I am trying to make the program allow only string inputs which consist of: A-Z and these special characters: . , ; : ? ! - ' "

Comment: I extended the answer. Using `Pattern.compile(...).matcher(...).find` or such might be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This will not solve the [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) problem but it will check if the string
contains illegal characters.

```java
    private boolean checkIllegalChars(String testString) {
       return testString.matches("[^\\w\\s,.:;?!'\"-]+");
    }
```